# HBase - Is it possible to get the region count of a table via an API?

Tags: java, hbase

I want to get region count per table in HBase 0.98.8. via Java API.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried [`getRegions()`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Admin.html#getRegions-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName-)?

Comment: @kichik, I'm using hbase 0.98.8. getRegions() is not available in version 0.98.8

Comment: Then what about [`getTableRegions()`](https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase-0.98.6-cdh5.3.3/devapidocs/index.html)?

Comment: Thanks kichik. I got count of Regions per table using getTableRegions()